# Comments toggle button open multiple comments

Tags: jquery, button, comments, toggle

I have this script for show/hide comments in the "main" page of my blog: [albertosotophotography](http://www.albertosotophotography.com)

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
    // Show/Hide Comments
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // Get #comments div
        var uniqueAppend = 1;
        var tempName = 'comments';
        while(jQuery("#comments").length > 0 ){
            jQuery("#comments").attr('id',tempName + uniqueAppend++).addClass('commentContainer')
        }
        var commentsDiv = jQuery('.commentContainer');

        // Only do this work if that div isn't empty
        if (commentsDiv.length) {

        // Hide #comments div by default
        jQuery(commentsDiv).hide();

        // Append a link to show/hide
        jQuery('<a/>')
            .attr('class', 'toggle-comments')
            .attr('href', '#')
            .html('Notes')
            .insertAfter(commentsDiv);

        // Encase button in .toggle-comments-container div
        jQuery('.toggle-comments').wrap(jQuery('<div/>', {
            class: 'toggle-comments-container'
        }))     

        // When show/hide is clicked
      jQuery('.toggle-comments').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();


        // Show/hide the div using jQuery's toggle()

        var commentContainer = jQuery(this).parent('.toggle-comments-container').siblings('.commentContainer');

        jQuery(commentContainer).fadeToggle('slow', function() {

            // change the text of the anchor
            var anchor = jQuery(commentContainer).siblings('.toggle-comments-container').children('.toggle-comments');
    var anchorText = anchor.text() == 'Notes' ? 'Hide' : 'Notes';
            jQuery(anchor).html(anchorText);

        });
        });

        } // End of commentsDiv.length

    }); // End of Show/Hide Comments
    </script>
```

The problem is when i press the button open all posts comments at the same time.
I want open only the comments of the button that i press.
I would be very grateful if someone can help me.
Thanks and best regards.

Alberto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the selectors in the following lines will fix your issue-

*Problem*

```
var commentContainer = jQuery(this).parent('.toggle-comments-container').siblings('.commentContainer');
var anchor = jQuery(commentContainer).siblings('.toggle-comments-container').children('.toggle-comments');
```

*Solution*

```
var commentContainer = jQuery(this).parent().prev();
var anchor = jQuery(commentContainer).next().children('.toggle-comments');
```

The problem is with the use of `.siblings()` which matches all elements with the same class name and thus selects all your comment nodes.
Also using `slideToggle` instead of `fadeToggle` might give you a better visual experience *(This line is just a design suggestion. Not related to the answer)*