# jQuery toggle for comment box

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am having difficulty in displaying and hiding my comments using jQuery. I am building a Rails app. Below is my html.erb and below that is my jQuery. As of now, it is behaving as a chain effect meaning if I click the button (.myButton) of the top most post, it opens the comments for all of the posts below it. However, if I click the button of the bottom most post, it only opens the comment box for that one. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I have tried consulting this Stack Overflow question but it hasn't helped me [Comments toggle button open multiple comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590650/comments-toggle-button-open-multiple-comments)

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="myButton">name</input>
...

<div  class="myDiv" >
    <% if post.comments %>
      <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
        <div class="comment">
          <div class="comment_name">
            <%= comment.name %>
          </div>
          <div class="comment_content">
            <%= comment.content %>
          </div>
          <% if comment.user == current_user %>
            <%= link_to post_comment_path(post, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <div class="comment_form">
      <%= form_for [post, post.comments.new] do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Add a comment...' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myButton').on('click', function(event) {        
         $(this).nextAll('.myDiv').toggle('swing');
    });
});
```

Comment: Its difficult to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: try to post the html code from your console to know how your structure looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `next` instead of `nextAll` like following. Hope this helps.

```js
$('.myButton').on('click', function (event) {
     $(this).next('.myDiv').toggle('swing');
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br /><input type="button" class="myButton" value="name" />
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment_name">
            Name 1
        </div>
        <div class="comment_content">
            Comment 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_form">
        <textarea placeholder="Add a comment....."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<br /><input type="button" class="myButton" value="name" />
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment_name">
            Name 2
        </div>
        <div class="comment_content">
            Comment 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_form">
        <textarea placeholder="Add a comment....."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<br /><input type="button" class="myButton" value="name"/>
<div class="myDiv">
    <div class="comment">
        <div class="comment_name">
            Name 3
        </div>
        <div class="comment_content">
            Comment 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_form">
        <textarea placeholder="Add a comment....."></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried using .next() but unfortunately when I click my button, nothing happens.

Comment: See the updated answer. It may help you. @user3318660

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked well. I was originally having issues with nextAll() working and next() not working, but this had to do with the placement of my button in my HTML.